# Bizarre simulation results with ADF test

Tags: simulation, matlab, augmented-dickey-fuller

I simulated the following processes
\begin{align}
   y_{1,t} = \beta y_{2,t} + \epsilon_{1,t} \\
   y_{2,t} = y_{2,t-1} + \epsilon_{2,t}, \; \; \; \epsilon_{2,t} \sim N(0,1) \\
   \epsilon_{1,t-1} = \rho \epsilon_{t-1} + u_t, u_t \sim N(0,1)
\end{align}

on MATLAB. Obviously, the second process is a random walk, so it is integrated of order 1 -- i.e., its first difference $(y_{2,t} - y_{2,t-1})$ is covariance stationnary. For the first process and its error term, I use the following values: $\rho=0.25$ and $\beta = 0.5$. This means that the error term is a covariance stationnary AR(1) and that $y_{1,t}$ has a unit root inherited from $y_{2,t}$. It also follows that
\begin{align}
   y_{1,t} - y_{1,t-1} = \beta(y_{2,t} - y_{2,t-1}) + (\epsilon_{1,t} - \epsilon_{1,t-1}) \\
   y_{1,t} - y_{1,t-1} = \beta \epsilon_{2,t} + (\rho - 1) \epsilon_{t-1} + u_t.
\end{align}

Since $\epsilon_{1,t}, \epsilon_{2,t}$ and $u_t$ are all covariance stationnary, the first difference of $y_{1,t}$ defined above must be covariance stationnary. So, **both processes** are integrated of order one.

In my simulation, I perform an Augmented Dickey-Fuller test on each series. As a reminder, the ADF test runs the following regression:
\begin{align}
    \Delta y_{i,t} := (y_{i,t} - y_{i,t-1}) \\
    \Delta y_{i,t} = \alpha + \delta y_{i,t-1} + \sum_{j=1}^p \Delta y_{i,t-j} + \eta_t.
\end{align}
The null hypothesis is that $y_{i,t}$ is integrated of order one which corresponds to $\delta = 0$. The alternative hypothesis I use in each case is an AR(1) with a constant. In principle, I can run the ADF test with $p=0$ for the second series, but the AR(1) term in the error of the first series means I need at least one lag.

Now, **here is what you should expect**: if I use a 0.05 threshold on the p-value of the test, I should erroneously find that $y_{1,t}$ is covariance stationnary 5 % of the time and likewise for $y_{2,t}$. More precisely, if I draw 100 Monte Carlo samples of, say, 250 observations, I expect 5 draws to lead me into error about each process, respectively. **Here is the weird thing**:

If I run the simulation with sample sizes of 150 or 250, I have no problem. I mean, it's just 100 MC draws, so it dances a bit around 95% non rejection, but it's close enough for both processes. However, if I drive the sample size way higher, say 10 000, everything is fine for $y_{2,t}$, but not for $y_{1,t}$ -- we're talking about mistakes well above 10%, so it's not the luck of the draw. And that doesn't make any sense. I don't know if I made a mistake coding or if there is something I missed at the conceptual level. So, I'm leaving you my code as well:

````
% Parameter values
rho  = [0, 0.25, 0.5];              % AR parameter
s    = [1,1];                       % Standard deviations of e(i,t)
n    = [150, 250, 10000];           % Sample size
burn = 100;                        % Number of burned-in periods
beta = 0.5;

% Dimensions of simulation study
S = 250;
J = size(rho,2);
K = size(n,2);

% Initialize matrices
b        = nan(2,1);
c        = nan(2,1);

ADF = zeros(S,J,K,2);

rng(12345);
for ss = 1:S
   fprintf(['\nSimulation :', num2str(ss), '\n\n']);
   for jj = 1:J
      for kk = 1:K

         % Simulate data
         y = zeros(burn+n(kk),2);
         e = y;
         for tt = 2:(burn+n(kk))
             y(tt,2) = y(tt-1,2)       + s(2)*randn(1);

             e(tt)   = rho(jj)*e(tt-1) + s(1)*randn(1);
             y(tt,1) = beta*y(tt,2)    + e(tt,1);
         end
         y(1:burn,:) = []; % Drop burn-in

         % ADF test selection
         for ii = 1:2
            [~,pvalue,~,~,~] = adftest(y(:,ii), 'model', ...
                                                'AR', 'lags', 1);
            % Here, c(ii) := H0 not rejected = y(:,i) is I(1)                              
            c(ii) = (pvalue >= 0.05);        
         end

         % Test choices
         ADF(ss,jj,kk,:) = c;

      end
   end
end

[mean((ADF(:,:,1,1) == 1)); ...
 mean((ADF(:,:,2,1) == 1)); ...
 mean((ADF(:,:,3,1) == 1))]

[mean((ADF(:,:,1,2) == 1)); ...
 mean((ADF(:,:,2,2) == 1)); ...
 mean((ADF(:,:,3,2) == 1))]

```
````

Comment: Could the lag length selection in the ADF specification be at fault? Your $y_{1,t} - y_{1,t-1} = \beta \epsilon_{2,t} + (\rho - 1) \epsilon_{t-1} + u_t$ where $\epsilon_1$ is autocorrelated to an infinite lag.

Comment: It would make sense, @RichardHardy. The problem would lie with the specification. I am after all applying exactly the same damn thing to both processes and it does work just fine for one of them.

Comment: You could try selecting the lag length using some rule, not just taking lag 1 each time, perhaps then you would be getting more sensible results.